# How can I not receive notifications while I have a certain screen open? - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my application I have several activities and one is chat. In this screen I have the ID of who is chatting with me and every time I send a message a push notification is sent with the message and the id of the person with whom I am chatting. While I'm chatting with this person I need to block notifications from them and only receive them if I don't have an open chat with that person. How do I do this? I'm using Firebase as a backend.

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        remoteMessage.notification?.let { notification ->

            val data = remoteMessage.data
            val type = data["type"] // chat message,like etc
            val id = data["id"] //userId

            val notificationChannelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
            val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

            val intent = setIntent(remoteMessage).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)

            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(notificationChannelId, CHANNEL_SPEEACHT, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            }

            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId)
                    .setContentTitle(notification.title ?: "")
                    .setContentText(notification.body ?: "")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorNotification))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not firebase-cloud-messaging related, because firebase-cloud-messaging is just a message channel, so you should do it in your own bussiness code.

A suggested way is that you can make a condition. if the activity is visable and the userid you received in onMessageReceived is the same as the userid you are chatting with, then you should not create your own notification in onMessageReceived function.

Answer (score 0):

- Set up properly of Notification task in android application.
- Send Notification to your device which have app to open screen.
- Open code. and write the command in Splash Screen.

> Splashscreen.java  -> onCreate()

```
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
       
        onNewIntent(getIntent());          //  onNewIntent  is the Main line.
       }
```

- after out of onCreate() method, **Override newIntent()** method by pressing Alt + Insert button.
- write code in ***newIntent()***  metho

  ```
      @Override
      protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent);
      if(intent.hasExtra("action")){
      if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("112")){
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  // opening in **Main Activity** to *redirect* in **Chat Screen**
           intent1.putExtra("action","112");   //  here "112" is the chat notification action.
           startActivity(intent1);
         }
        }
      }
  ```

> - Open ***MainActivity.java***  -> onCreate()

- write code to find out intent with it actions if intent have available data.

  ```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          // check if intent have action in data.
          if(getIntent().hasExtra("action")){  

          // check if data available then action == 112 is available or not.
          if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action").equals("112")){   

          // opening ChattingActivity.java if all scenario is not nullable.
          startActivity(new Intent(this,ChattingActivity.class));  
        }
       }
  ```